# Breakpoint() in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, breakpoints

What is the new breakpoint() in Python 3.7 and how we use it efficiently?
The documentation has provided the statement that This function drops you into the debugger at the call site. But, how do we use it?

```
a = "Hello,"
b = " World!"
print("a > ",a)
breakpoint()
print("b > ",b)
```

Comment: You use it like any other function, your code's fine.

Comment: And what happens? Your code is executed up to `breakpoint()`, the interpreter pass the control to a debugger, by default (your case) it is `pdb` that prints the qualified (by the module pathname and line no.) next line of code, prints the prompt `"(Pdb) "` and awaits for a command

Comment: Run your code and see what happens—it should be fairly obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s recommended to use this for debugging so that you can easily hook other third-party debuggers on the fly. Create a script with your code and run it. 
For example:

```
C:\Python373>notepad break_001.py

C:\Python373>python.exe break_001.py
a >  Hello,
> c:\python373\break_001.py(5)<module>()
-> print("b > ",b)
(Pdb) c
b >   World!

C:\Python373>
```

This allows you to use Pdb debugger.